# Master of roads

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is it OK (in the spirit of language) to call truck driver, or any professional driver "master of roads"? Is there any other meaning to this phrase (religious or something)? Thanks.

EDIT: I came here after thorough google inspection and no definite answer. To clarify, it should be said in affectionate  way to someone close, husband, brother etc... (even slight tone of mocking is really not wanted).

EDIT 2: No, road master is something else as far as I know. The expression or phrase that am looking for is equivalent to  "the ace of the sky( or skies)" (for air pilots) but for truck drivers and similar professionals  managing (heavy) vehicles on long routes. Skilled, seasoned professionals, "aces" in their job.(Apart from "king" if possible.) I see now, I should have asked this as a question.

Comment: No, but sometimes "King of the road" or "Knight of the road" are used for an experienced road user.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Nicking that to add to my answer, good point.

Comment: @SamBC fine, I didn't think it was enough on its own to answer the question, hence a comment. BTW never heard "Master of roads" used ;)

Comment: 'Master of the road' or 'Roadmaster' perhaps? Not heard of either though

Answer (score 1):

Well, most top Google results for that phrase lead to a book, either store pages for it or reviews or so on. It looks (from a brief inspection) to be an indie fantasy novel. So some people might get that association. It's also been used more-or-less casually about anyone who travels a lot on roads and knows them well.

It is not, in general, a familiar phrase, and I would say that it may be seen as whimsical - and potentially mocking. That depends on context, audience and tone.

As Weather Vane noted in the comments, however, an expression that is commonly used in situations like that is "king of the road".